# Dar Hide/Show e mostrar apens conteudo do item clicado

Tags: jquery, html

Estou querendo mostrar/esconder a div ao clicar nela mesmo e esconder ao clicar em outro item, estou apenas conseguindo esconder ao clicar em outro item, ao clicar nela mesmo não estou conseguindo esconder.

**Exemplo de como está o código**

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
    let posicao = $(this).index(".opener");
        $('.level0.nav-submenu.nav-panel--dropdown.nav-panel').hide();
        if ($('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').hide(); 
        } else {
        $('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').show();
        }
    });
```

```css
.opener {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navi opt-fx-fade-inout opt-sb0 opt-sob opt-hide480 centered with-bullets nav-mobile acco nav-mobile-triggerable">
<ul>      
    
 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-1">
 <span>Datas Especiais</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste1</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-2">
 <span>Ocasiões</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste2</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-3">
 <span>Categorias</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>test3</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-4">
 <span>Flores</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste4</span></li></ul></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: a pergunta para mim está um pouco confusa, não sei se os outros concordam, mas consideraria editar e inserir trecho do código dentro da pergunta.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e deixei mais simples, creio que esteja melhor de entender, executando o código que eu coloquei acho que da para ter uma noção.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso O código já está no executável, gostaria que eu colocasse ele novamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troquei a lógica no código colocando o hide que era acima do IF, dentro do if, como ele escondia todos os elementos ao ser clicado independente do IF era como se a outra execução na linha 4 não fizesse efeito, pois não estaria visível sempre por esconder antes e exibir logo depois no else.

```js
    $(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
    let posicao = $(this).index(".opener");
        if ($('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').hide(); 
        } else {
        $('.level0.nav-submenu.nav-panel--dropdown.nav-panel').hide();
        $('.nav-item.level0.nav-' + (posicao+1) + ' ul').show();
        }
    });
```

```css
.opener {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navi opt-fx-fade-inout opt-sb0 opt-sob opt-hide480 centered with-bullets nav-mobile acco nav-mobile-triggerable">
<ul>      
    
 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-1">
 <span>Datas Especiais</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste1</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-2">
 <span>Ocasiões</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste2</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-3">
 <span>Categorias</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>test3</span></li></ul></li>

 <li class="nav-item level0 nav-4">
 <span>Flores</span>
 <span class="opener">\/</span>
 <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
 <li class="nav-item classic">
 <span>teste4</span></li></ul></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Se eu percebi corretamente o que quer fazer, pode simplificar bastante a sua lógica utilizando apenas a função [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) do Jquery. Para isso só tem de partir do elemento onde clicou e chegar ao que quer esconder chamando o [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle(); 
});
```

O `$(this)` parte do elemento clicado o `.opener` e com `next()` chega ao `<ul>` que quer mostrar.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.opener {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navi opt-fx-fade-inout opt-sb0 opt-sob opt-hide480 centered with-bullets nav-mobile acco nav-mobile-triggerable">
  <ul>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-1">
      <span>Datas Especiais</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste1</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-2">
      <span>Ocasiões</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste2</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-3">
      <span>Categorias</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>test3</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-4">
      <span>Flores</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste4</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Desta forma irá fazer com que apenas sejam fechados os que clicamos diretamente. Se clicar num e de seguida noutro o primeiro não fecha. Para contemplar esse caso já é necessário alterar um pouco a lógica, fechando os outros apenas quando vai mostrar um novo.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.opener', function() {
  if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
    $('.level0.nav-submenu.nav-panel--dropdown.nav-panel').hide();
  
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.opener {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainmenu" class="navi opt-fx-fade-inout opt-sb0 opt-sob opt-hide480 centered with-bullets nav-mobile acco nav-mobile-triggerable">
  <ul>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-1">
      <span>Datas Especiais</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste1</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-2">
      <span>Ocasiões</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste2</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-3">
      <span>Categorias</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>test3</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item level0 nav-4">
      <span>Flores</span>
      <span class="opener">\/</span>
      <ul class="level0 nav-submenu nav-panel--dropdown nav-panel" style="display: none;">
        <li class="nav-item classic">
          <span>teste4</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Faltou apenas esconder quando clicar nos outros elementos.

Comment: @BrenoCosta Correto! Agradeço o comentário.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer, estava errando em uma coisinha, mas agora faz exatamente o que eu preciso, irei postar a resposta aqui, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se a galera já respondeu, então vou deixar minha contribuição. 
Acredito que a solução abaixo é mais simples, limpa e fácil de entender/programar. Não há necessidades de ifs ou testes em geral; somente de pura manipulação de árvore.
([Link para visualizar no Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlanVncs/pen/xXaPxY))

```js
// Espera o documento ser carregado
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  // Atribui um callback ao evento click em todos os elementos .show-content
  $(".show-content").click(function() {
    
    // Obtém e salva o elemento que será trabalhado (Escondido ou mostrado)
    content_div = $(this).parent().find(".content");
    
    // Esconde todos os elementos, EXCETO (not) o elemento em que se está trabalhando
    $("div.menu > div > div.content").not(content_div).addClass("hidden");
    
    // Alterna, sem a necessidade de if, a visibilidade do elemento
    $(this).parent().find(".content").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
div.menu > div > span.title{
  font-size: 30px;
}

div.menu > div > span.show-content{
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  
  <div>
    <span class="title">Título 1</span> <span class="show-content">Ver mais</span>
    <div class="content hidden">
      Conteúto 1
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span class="title">Título 2</span> <span class="show-content">Ver mais</span>
    <div class="content hidden">
      Conteúto 2
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <span class="title">Título 3</span> <span class="show-content">Ver mais</span>
    <div class="content hidden">
      Conteúto 3
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```